# Python 3 | remove duplicates based on index value and covert output into table format

Tags: python-3.x

Using **Python**
I am getting a output as in below format, I need to remove duplicate based on first index value and then convert it into a table format.

**Input:**

```
('a','b','c','d')
('a','d','e','f')
('b','j','d','e')
```

**Output:**

```
('a','b','c','d')
('b','j','d','e')
```

Then Table format

### A B C D

```
a b c d
b j d e
```

Comment: Can you include the code that you have done and what are the problem you're facing ?

Comment: It'a Netapp code, i am getting output in below format ('a','b','c','d') ('a','d','e','f') ('b','j','d','e') in which i want to remove duplicate based on 1st index value and then convert it into a table format

Comment: Improved formatting.